# Is there an ASP.NET databindable control (like Repeater), which only expects a single item?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying display lots of properties from a business object on a Web Form. I could of course, create loads of labels and assign all the values in code-behind, but I feel there must be a less verbose way.

What I want is something like an asp:Panel but where you can specify a datasource. It doesn't seem like Panels support any kind of databinding.

What I'd like is something like this

```
// C#
panel.DataSource = theCompany;
panel.DataBind();
```

Then:

```
// ASPX

<asp:Panel runat="server">
    Name: <%# Eval("Name") %>
    Phone: <%# Eval("Phone") %> 
    ...
</asp:Panel>
```

..but I can't find anything which will allow me to work in this way.

I thought I might be able to use **asp:FormView** but this just gives the error "Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource."

A caveat is that I *do not* want to call a global DataBind() (this has caused us no-end of problems in the past) - I would like the databind to be constrained to a particular part of the page.

Comment: I think the Formview will do what you looking for.

Comment: Yes, the FormView is your control. The FormView control is used to display a single record at a time from a data source as explained in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227992%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I can't seem to bind a DataRow or a business object class to a FormView as it just says "Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource."

Comment: Simply create an `IEnumerable` from your type. Like `formView.DataSource = new List { theCompany };` or if you have a collction of DataRow then `formView.DataSource = dataRows.Select(dataRow => new YourBusinessObject { initialization code }).ToList();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you can do this using a Panel, but you have to assign your business object to a page property first, as there's no way to set the business object as a "DataSource" for the panel (as you would for a Repeater control, for instance).

Once the object is assigned as a page property, you can then use the following syntax in the .aspx to access the properties of that object, without needing to manually assign each item to control values in code behind:

```
<%# Company.Name %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to databind (although you can). What you need is a simple expression evaluator. Add a property to your code behind like this

```
public string Test { get; set; }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Test = "<script>alert('test');</script>";
}
```

Then use it to render code directly to the page like this

```
The value: <%: Test %>
```

Note that the <%: syntax escapes the input. If you wish to NOT escape the input then you can use <%= syntax. Note that you don't need to have a string object you can access any properties you like for example

```
The value lenght: <%: Test.Length %>
```

Comment: I tried to use <%= but it was hard to control the timing of when this happened. With the databinding syntax of <%# you can choose the exact time when the databind occurs.

Comment: Well it happens last. I don't see why this would be a problem. Just compute the data whenever you see fit and it will appear on the page when the page is rendered.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DetailsView`. You can add it from the Toolbox. It's for Single Row Data Presentation.

```
<asp:DetailsView runat="server">
    Name: <%# Eval("Name") %>
    Phone: <%# Eval("Phone") %>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: Details view doesn't work in my case as I also need to call some page helper methods ( eg: `<%# GetBaseUrl() %>`).

Comment: This throws a `HttpParseException`. Perhaps you are missing some sort of template block in your code?

Answer (score 2):

Use The below:

```
<asp:DetailsView runat="server">
    Name: <%# Eval("Name") %>
    Phone: <%# Eval("Phone") %>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using DetailsView. Its perfect for what you want. Showing single row of data only and that too in two column form.

Comment: Because I got the same error I got when trying to use asp:FormView.

Comment: what is the base type of your datasource?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a standard `Repeater`, databound with an array containing a single item.

```
Repeater.DataSource = new [] { theCompany };
Repeater.DataBind();
```

Advantage over databinding to a `Panel`: you can still use the `ItemType` attribute, and have access to the nice strongly typed `Item` object and don't have to go about using `Eval`, i.e.:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" Id="Repeater" ItemType="CompanyViewModel">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Name: <%# Item.Name %>
        Phone: <%# Item.Phone %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

(Replace "CompanyViewModel" with the Type of your: "theCompany".)

You can also try experimenting with `DetailsView`, but it's not as malleable as a Repeater.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own user control that shows the properties of the objects. You can use reflection to read property names and values and display in control.

Create a property for your object in your user control. Inside user control code behind write function Show() with below code.

```
//Build html strin from all propeties
PropertyInfo[] properties = yourObject.GetType().GetProperties();

string lbl = "<label>{0}</label>";
string value= "<span>{0}</span>";
string tab ="\t";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
{

    var label = string.Format(lbl,pi.Name);
    var val =  string.Format(value, pi.GetValue(yourObject, null))
    sb.Append(label+tab+val);
    sb.Append("<br/>")    

}
Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Now in your pager add that control and sets its object property in code behind like

```
myControl.MyObject = yourObject;
myControl.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

NickG's answer will work... however consider two scenarios.

1. If your business object is ever null, the page will crash with an "Object Reference" error. This can be avoided with a cumbersome looking 
   <% if(MyObject != null) { %><%= MyObject.Prop %><% } %> 
   ... but doing that every time makes for messy code.
2. If your page uses PostBack processing via UpdatePanel, the business object will have to be **reloaded** to the property every time the Page lifecycle runs... **even if that portion of the page isn't being redrawn**. This is because IIS will resolve all the <%= MyObject.Prop %> references regardless, causing wasted CPU cycles and probably wasted database calls if your object is coming from a database.

For these reasons I always use a Repeater control, which is lightweight, supports **ViewState**, can easily be assigned a one item list, and avoids the aforementioned issues. Here's an example using the HttpContext.Current.Request object as a "business object".

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTest" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                Request.URL = <%# Eval("Url") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var objTest = Request; //Using the Request object as a test business object

        rptTest.DataSource = new List<System.Web.HttpRequest>() { objTest };
        rptTest.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this work we can customize ASP.NET Panel by inheriting it and using Custom Server control for ASP.NET

Use Below Code to modify the ASP.NET Panel in an ASP.NET Custom Server Control Project:

```
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:CustomPanel runat=server></{0}:CustomPanel>")]
public class CustomPanel : Panel
{
    [Bindable(true)]
    public object MyDataSource
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Localizable(true)]
    public StringBuilder Text
    {
        get;

        set;
    }

    public void MyDataBind()
    {
        Text = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in MyDataSource.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            Text.Append(string.Format("<b>{0}</b>", p.Name));
            Text.Append(":");
            if (p.GetIndexParameters() == null || p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
                Text.Append(p.GetValue(MyDataSource, null));
            Text.Append("<br />");
        }
    }

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        output.Write(Text);
    }
}
```

Then add this control's reference and toolbox item to your ASP.NET page:

```
<cc2:CustomPanel ID="MyCustomPanel" runat="server">
</cc2:CustomPanel>
```

Use the control as shown below:

```
        MyCustomPanel.MyDataSource = theCompany;
        MyCustomPanel.MyDataBind();
```