# If condition with Eval value on aspx page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, treelist

I'am using ASP.NET Web Forms, and I have to do something like this:

```
 <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="cellContent" Visible='<%# (bool)Eval("IsFolder")? false:true %>'>
                        <% if(Eval("Type").ToString() == "0"){ %>
                            <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Content/Icon/analiza.png" Width="30px" Height="30px" ImageAlign="Left" />
                        <% } else if(Eval("Type").ToString() == "1") {%>
                            <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Content/Icon/raport.png" Width="30px" Height="30px" ImageAlign="Left" /> 
                        <% } %>
                    </asp:Panel>
```

but I'am getting error "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.". How can I achieve that? "Type" can have 3 values: 0, 1, 2. In MVC something like this is very easy, but I was forced to use Web Forms and Devexpress TreeList control, and cant find answer how to do such simple think :/

Answer (score 0):

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575282/is-there-an-asp-net-databindable-control-like-repeater-which-only-expects-a-s) might shed some light onto your problem.

The easiest option seems to use `DetailsView` and set its `.DataSource` and then `.DataBind()`.

```
<asp:DetailsView id="dvTest" runat="server">
   Type: <%# Eval("Type") %>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Then in your code, make a List() of the values (0, 1, 2). Do `dvTest.DataSource=numbersList` and then `dvTest.DataBind()`.